# Installed WordPress with Softaculous. Should I upgradeManually or with Softaculous?

Tags: upgrade

I've setup my first blog with WordPress and I love the framework. I've created sites from scratch on a LAMP stack so I've even been able to tweak my theme and write a plugin or two.

So, here's my question: I installed WordPress with Softaculous because it was easy and it worked the first time. Now, I've been upgrading WordPress and all of my themes and plugins manually from the admin panel on the blog. I thought this was a good way to go but I just logged into Softaculous to create a new blog and I noticed that it was telling me to upgrade the first blog that I created.

Can I ignore the upgrade message in Softaculous and continue to upgrade the blog manually? Should I just use Softaculous to make it easy to upgrade multiple installs? Can I mix the two?

Thanks for your hints, tips and tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation with my WordPress install and Softaculous, what I found was that the version it was telling me to install (or upgrade to) was actually a minor version BEHIND the version of WP that was considered to be current at the time.

In my situation I simply ignored it and had no issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can take take a backup via Softaculous :
http://softaculous.com/docs/How_to_Backup_an_Installation

and then Upgrade your installation via Softaculous :
http://softaculous.com/docs/How_to_upgrade_installations